# LWS enablement for LWC:REF directive and then anchor , lightning button not working in aura component

Tags: aura, lws

I had to enable LWS in my salesforce org to work with lwc:ref directive. But after switching that setting on, anchor tag and lightning button in my aura component are not working. I have used anchor tag in aura component to call a function on controller side in onclick event.

Aura code:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!boolean flag}">
 <a onclick="{!c.functionRemove}"
     id="{!Code}">
       <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:clear"
         variant="bare" alternativeText="remove" />
</a>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: Please add relevant code to your question to facilitate reproducing the problem. And please correct the title, which sounds like you use lwc:ref in Aura.

Comment: updated and added aura anchor tag, button code